# Openpgpjs: unable to verify a detached signature

Tags: openpgp.js

The public key can be downloaded from [here](https://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?op=get&options=mr&search=0x8e3a14e8)

That is the string i would like to verify:

```
6mjdvgmdvggpyoaf.onion
```

That is the detached signature:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
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=vn/m
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

Here is the code:

```
var pubkey = openpgp.key.readArmored(key.trim());
var msg = openpgp.message.readSignedContent(domain, signed_block);
var result = msg.verify(pubkey);
console.log(result.valid);
```

The result log is:

```
null
```

Deeping into code the function called for verify can be found at:

https://openpgpjs.org/openpgpjs/doc/message.js.html

At line 367:

```
if (keyPacket) {

  verifiedSig.keyid = signatureList[i].issuerKeyId;

  verifiedSig.valid = signatureList[i].verify(keyPacket, literalDataList[0]);

} else {

  verifiedSig.keyid = signatureList[i].issuerKeyId;

  verifiedSig.valid = null;

}
```

keyPacket is not found but i can't figure why, looks like a problem with the signed block (maybe??) but i don't know enough about Openpgp internals to know what to do.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: A little deeper: https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/issues/496

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

```
var pubkey = openpgp.key.readArmored(key.trim()).keys;
```